# JavaFX ToolBar resize to childrens dynamic widths

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11

I've had to switch TabPane for a Toolbar using ToggleButtons instead of Tabs. This is because I need finer control over the 'Tab's' content and graphics and Drag n Drop functionality than I can get with Tab as it comes out of the box. I can make Tab behave and look the way I want but because I need to set my Text on a Label in the Tab's graphic (an HBox in my case) it means the overflow ContextMenu doesn't have any visible text. I'd also like the other layout properties from my Tabs to be inherited in the ContextMent items and Toolbar provides this for me nicely (background colour and images laid out next to the 'Tab's text.
The issue I have is that the images that are displayed on the Tabs, now ToggleButtons (FakeTabs in my code), are updated dynamically and so change the width of the ToggleButton. If I set the following in FakeTab:

`//set minSize to prevent Label text being truncated.`

```
`this.setMinSize(Button.USE_PREF_SIZE, Button.USE_PREF_SIZE);`
```

so that the text on the Label next to the images doesn't get truncated the Toolbar doesn't resize and the >> button to open the ContextMenu ends up over the last ToggleButton but it also misses off some of the ToggleButtons from the menu so you can't access them.
Is there a way to set the ToolBar up so that it will resize to it's children's widths as they change or can I force a relayout? When I say resize, I want it to maintain it's actually width but recalculate which ToggleButtons need to be in the ContextMenu and keep the >> button on the far right not over a ToggleButton.
I've tried various things to .requestLayout() on the ToolBar but so far no success.

My reprex adds some of my FakeTabs (ToggleButtons) and then after the application is run will gradually add some Circles (substitues for the images that are added in my application). This causes the issue where the ToggleButtons get wider and the ToolBar doesn't resize to accomodate the children's new widths.
Removing

`this.setMinSize(Button.USE_PREF_SIZE, Button.USE_PREF_SIZE);`

From FakeTab results in the FakeTab's text getting truncated as the Circles are added which is not workable for me.

Thanks for any help.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeLineCap;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class MainApp extends Application {

    private CustomTabPane customTabPane;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        customTabPane = new CustomTabPane();
        VBox.setVgrow(customTabPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        VBox vbox = new VBox(2.0);
        vbox.getChildren().setAll(customTabPane);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setMaxWidth(800);
        root.setMaxHeight(400);
        root.setCenter(vbox);

        //add some fake tabs
        List<DataModel> dataModels = Arrays.asList(

                new DataModel("Tab1 name ", new int[]{0, 0, 255}),
                new DataModel("Tab2 name 22", new int[]{0, 0, 140}),
                new DataModel("Tab3 name 333", new int[]{0, 0, 100}),
                new DataModel("Tab4 name 4444", new int[]{255, 0, 0}),
                new DataModel("Tab5 name 55555", new int[]{100, 0, 0}),
                new DataModel("Tab6 name 666666", new int[]{0, 255, 0}),
                new DataModel("Tab7 name 7777777", new int[]{0, 140, 0}),
                new DataModel("Tab8 name 88888888", new int[]{0, 100, 0}),
                new DataModel("Tab9 name 999999999", new int[]{50, 0, 50}),
                new DataModel("Tab10 name xxxxxxxxxx", new int[]{110, 0, 50}));
        for (DataModel data : dataModels) {
            addFakeTab(data);
        }
        //simulated Images being updated to Tabs after the CustomTabPane has been populated with FakeTabs.
        Task task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws InterruptedException {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        updateTabIcons();
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        new Thread(task).start();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("CustomTabPane");
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    /**
     * Fake updating FakeTabs with 'images'.
     */
    private void updateTabIcons() {
        for (int i = 0; i < customTabPane.getToolBarNodes().size(); i++) {
            Node node = customTabPane.getToolBarNodes().get(i);
            if (node instanceof FakeTab) {
                ((FakeTab) node).addImage(createCircle());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add a circle where the image would go
     **/
    private Circle createCircle() {
        Circle circle = new Circle(10);
        circle.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        circle.setStrokeType(StrokeType.INSIDE);
        circle.setStrokeWidth(2.0);
        circle.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.BUTT);
        circle.setStroke(Color.WHITE);

        return circle;
    }

    private void addFakeTab(DataModel data) {
        FakeTab fakeTab = new FakeTab(data);
        customTabPane.addTab(fakeTab);
    }

    class CustomTabPane extends VBox {
        private StackPane stackPane;
        private ToolBar toolBar;

        public CustomTabPane() {
            toolBar = new ToolBar();
            stackPane = new StackPane();

            this.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
            this.getChildren().setAll(toolBar, stackPane);
        }

        public ObservableList<Node> getToolBarNodes() {
            return toolBar.getItems();
        }

        public void addTab(ToggleButton toggleButton) {
            toolBar.getItems().add(toggleButton);
        }

    }

    class DataModel {
        private String id;
        private int[] rgbColor;

        public DataModel(String id, int[] rgbColor) {
            this.id = id;
            this.rgbColor = rgbColor;
        }

        public int[] getRgbColor() {
            return rgbColor;
        }

        public String getRgbString() {
            return "" + rgbColor[0] + "," + rgbColor[1] + "," + rgbColor[2];
        }

        public String getStringId() {
            return id;
        }
    }

}
```

FakeTab class:

```
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;


public class FakeTab extends ToggleButton {

    private Label label;
    private HBox imageHBox;
    private MainApp.DataModel dataModel;


    public FakeTab(MainApp.DataModel dataModel) {
        super("");
        this.dataModel = dataModel;
        //set minSize to prevent Label text being truncated.
        this.setMinSize(Button.USE_PREF_SIZE, Button.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        label = new Label();
        imageHBox=new HBox(1.0);
        HBox hBox = new HBox(imageHBox,label);
        hBox.setStyle("-fx-padding: 1.0em;");
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        this.setGraphic(hBox);
        this.setUserData("" + dataModel.getStringId());
        label.setText("" + dataModel.getStringId());

        int[] rgb = dataModel.getRgbColor();
        Color color = getFXColor(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], 1.0);
        String style = "-fx-background-color:rgb(" + dataModel.getRgbString() + ");-fx-text-fill:" + (isColorDark(color) ? "white" : "black") + ";";
        String style2 = "-fx-background-color:rgb(" + dataModel.getRgbString() + ");-fx-text-fill:transparent;";
        this.setStyle(style2);
        label.setStyle(style);

    }

    //add a Circle to simulate the effect adding images has.
    public void addImage(Circle circle){
        imageHBox.getChildren().add(circle);
    }

    private  Color getFXColor(int iR, int iG, int iB, double opacity) {
        double r = ((double) iR) / 255;
        double g = ((double) iG) / 255;
        double b = ((double) iB) / 255;
        return new Color(r, g, b, opacity);
    }

    private  boolean isColorDark(Color color) {
        boolean isDark = false;
        double boundary = 0.4980392156862745;
        int colorChk = 0;
        if (color.getRed() > boundary) {
            colorChk += 1;
        }
        if (color.getGreen() > boundary) {
            colorChk += 2;
        }
        if (color.getBlue() > boundary) {
            colorChk += 4;
        }
        switch (colorChk) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 4:
                isDark = true;
                break;
        }
        return isDark;
    }

}
```

Comment: have a look at the source code of TabPaneSkin, it should handle that problem when its popup is showing - you can get ideas to copy from :)

Answer (score 1):

I had already looked through the source code for ToolBarSkin as it handles the overflow in the way I need (rendering the background colors of the ToggleButtons and including the Children such as images). It has a private boolean needsUpdate which is set to try when items are removed or added but not when the dimensions of the chilren items change. For now the hack I've used is some reflection to access this private field so I can set it to true before requesting the ToolBar to relayout it's children. It does what I need but I'd prefer not to have to use reflection.

```
 //use reflection to access private member field needsUpdate. This is the boolean
                //used by the skin to trigger a relayout of the ToolBar when items are added/removed.
                //we need to use this to force a relayout when children change sizes too.
                Field f1 = ToolBarSkin.class.getDeclaredField("needsUpdate");
                f1.setAccessible(true);
                f1.setBoolean(skin, true);
                this.requestLayout();
```

Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Where did you get the value of 'skin' from the existing toolbar? I'm assuming 'this' is the toolbar object?  Where does this snippet of code get placed in your example?

Answer (score 0):

@codeDr

I wrote a class that extended ToolBar and the overrode the createDefaultSkin() method. In this I created  a ToolBarSkin skin.

Hope that helps?

```
public class CustomToolBar extends ToolBar {
private ToolBarSkin skin;

@Override
protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
    skin = new ToolBarSkin(this);
    return skin;
}


public void redoLayout() {
    if (skin != null) {
        //force update
        try {
            //use reflection to access private member field needsUpdate. This is the boolean
            //used by the skin to trigger a relayout of the ToolBar when items are added/removed.
            //we need to use this to force a relayout when children change sizes too.
            Field f1 = ToolBarSkin.class.getDeclaredField("needsUpdate");
            f1.setAccessible(true);
            f1.setBoolean(skin, true);
            this.requestLayout();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}